# Converting DEM in degree decimal to meter using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, coordinate-system

i am trying to make cell size of satellite image and DEM equal for Maxent.

cell size of satellite image is in metric but DEM is in degree decimal.

how can i convert DEM in degree decimal to meter using ArcMap?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by using the [Project Raster (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html%23//00170000007q000000) tool to transform your DEM from a Geographic Coordinate System in decimal degrees to a Projected Coordinate System in meters.